# how to get the output info simply?

Tags: python-3.x

The info output in the console is in the form of string,sometimes we want to get some useful info from it.

```
>>> open('out.txt', 'w')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='out.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp936'>
>>> open('out.txt', 'w').name
'out.txt'
>>> open('out.txt', 'w').mode
'w'
>>> open('out.txt', 'w').encoding
'cp936'
>>> repr(open('out.txt', 'w')).split(" ")[0][1:]
'_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

I get part of info with `repr(open('out.txt', 'w')).split(" ")[0][1:]`,is there more simple way to get the same output info as '_io.TextIOWrapper'?

Comment: `str(open('out.txt', 'w')).split(" ")[0][1:]` is 1 character shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begs the question of what on earth you are trying to do, but for Python 3 you would use:

```
>>> '{0.__module__}.{0.__qualname__}'.format(type(open('out.txt', 'w')))
'_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

Note that `__qualname__` doesn't exist prior to Python 3.3.

The difference between `__qualname__` and `__name__` is that `__qualname__` will include information about the enclosing scope if something was nested in a class or a function.

Deriving names for something which includes both module name and type of object can be tricky as this rule above doesn't always work for certain things. So as a general mechanism for getting a complete name for an object, this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Is is the a instance of file object, so you can get its `__class__` attr:

```
>>> open('out.txt', 'w').__class__
 _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: Which Python version is that. On Python 3.4 if doing str() or repr() on that yields "<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>", so isn't just the name, but also the other stuff around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type as a string like this:

```
>>> type(open('out.txt', 'w')).__name__
'TextIOWrapper'
```

Comment: That's not the same as `'_io.TextIOWrapper'`.

Comment: Indeed.. perhaps it should be a comment, but the formatting is easier this way, and it's not crystal clear that OP wants *exactly* the same info.